# Scheme lambda expression in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Can Some one help explain why

```
(define gg (lambda (ff x) (ff x x x))
```

has all of these properties? Thanks

```
gg requires two arguments when called
gg's first argument should be a function
gg's first argument should be a function that accepts 3 arguments
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `gg` is a lambda with two arguments, `ff` and `x`.
2. `ff` is used in the expression `(ff x x x)` inside the lambda, so `ff` should be callable.
3. The expression `(ff x x x)` has three arguments, so `ff` should be a function taking three arguments.

Comment: i thought (ff x x x) was how the lambda is processed? In a sense, the inner function of lambda.

Comment: What do you mean by "how the lambda is processed" or "inner function"?

Comment: ((lambda(ff x) (ff x x x)) 2), 2 gets passed into the lambda expression ff x then processed by ff x x x

Comment: That's an invalid expression, since the lambda expects two arguments and you're passing only one. You could, however, use `((lambda (ff x) (ff x x x)) + 2)`, which would be the same as calling `(+ 2 2 2)`. In this instance, `ff` is `+` and `x` is 2. And `+` happens to be a function which can take any number of arguments, and in particular, it can take 3 arguments.

Comment: for if i put another thing in the lambda  I could do this and have the 3rd expression  be used like ((lambda (ff x) (ff x x x)(ff x x x x)) + 2 2 2 2)

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty your new lambda expression has two function calls inside it. The result of first call is ignored the result of second call is returned. In the first call, `ff` receives 3 arguments; in 2nd - 4 arguments. So it must be capable to receive 3 or 4 arguments. -- The top lambda expression expect two arguments, `ff` and `x`, but you give it 5 values: `+`, and the `2`s. This will cause an error, argument number mismatch.